# Recovering Lost Mode then Deletion from Find my Iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

I have 2 iphones and today I had an experiment; from **Find my Iphone** App I have turned on **lost mode** in one of my phones and then I've **erased** it. Now I see

"This iPhone has been lost. Please call me.

"1421421"(my phone number)

on its screen and its not possible to do anything with it.
Couldn't find a solution after checking icloud and some search. Anybody have an idea how I can take it back?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIN to unlock the device and connect to the internet (if needed)

Then open the find my phone app and go to that device.

Tap/select **Turn Off Lost Mode**

Alternatively, connect it to iTunes to complete the unlock on that device. Worst case, you have a chance to try backing it up (assuming you don't have a current backup). At that point, you can restore the device in iTunes.